# Enable ZMQ in docker IRI node

Tags: iri-node, local

I've set up a private tangle following the guide on [iotaledger/compass](https://github.com/iotaledger/compass/blob/master/docs/HOWTO_private_tangle.md). Now I'm trying to enable zmq. I tried to change the following in the 03_run_coordinator.sh file.  Changes are adding the 5556 port and the zmq_enabled configuration.

```
docker pull iotaledger/iri:latest
docker run -p 5556:5556 -t --net host --rm -v $scriptdir/db:/iri/data -v $scriptdir/snapshot.txt:/snapshot.txt -p 14265 iotaledger/iri:latest \
       --testnet \
       ..
       --zmq_enabled true
```

Unfortunately, it seems like zmq is still disabled.

Comment: Does the Coordinator support ZMQ? You should add it to `02_run_iri.sh` if you want to enable ZMQ for your node.